# VB.net DLL function takes too long for response .. How to timeout?

Tags: vb.net

In my program I need to make call to external DLL function in below mentioned way

```
private sub myFunc

Dim dllObj as OtherDLL.Service
Dim retval as boolean

retval = dllObj.doSomething

end Sub
```

Sometime doSomething funciton takes long to respond ( 5 -6 minutes) 
I want to implement it in a manner that, if doSomething function does not return in 10 seconds then retval  should be false

What is best way to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement this in a similar program sometime ago. 
I used a seperate thread via backgroundworker, which worked quite well.
Now, with the await / async mechanism there should be an easy way to do is: fire up a task await it and when it's taking too long, kill it.